# Data type of a Keyword attribute in an XML event log

Tags: xml, event-log

I'm just wondering how will i be able to save a keyword attribute coming from an xml eventlog (.evtx). As an example, a keyword value is 0x800000000000000, what kind of datatype is this in sql if i'm going to save it in a table.

Comment: That looks like a hexadecimal format, but you could save it as a string (varchar in SQL).

Comment: it maps to a long datatype in a c# class, so when i iterate thru the collection of attributes i received a translated value, how would i be able to retain the value?

Comment: Not sure I follow, but a long is `Int64`, which is a `bigint` in SQL.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But what I'm trying to do is to read a record in event log (.evtx) and there is a keyword attribute, I use the EventLogRecord class, the keyword maps to a nullable long datatype, but when i tried to read the log, the keyword (hexa) from the .evtx, changed to a series of long numbers.

Comment: So you're saying that `0x800000000000000` becomes `5.76460752303E+17` (or the non-exponent equivalent), and you want to keep the original format?

Comment: Yes, i want to keep the original format instead.

Comment: You could try something like `string keywordValue = intValue.ToString("X");`, where `intValue` is the long value from the `EventLogRecord` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the `long` value and use `.ToString()` with the "X" formatter to get the hexadecimal value, but you'll need to add the "0x" manually.

Here's a trivial example:

```
long keyword = 0x800000000000000;
string hexValue = String.Format("0x{0}", keyword.ToString());
```

The long value for `keyword` is `576460752303423488`, and the value in `hexValue` is `0x800000000000000`.

Adjust and adapt to fit your code :)